# Laravel 5.3 Validate Multiple Request Show Errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Hi I have a controller that inserts multiple values into 2 tables from 1 form, I can validate them but only one at a time. Only If I click on the button to insert it shows the erros of the second validation.

```
public function store(CreateRequest $request, RegisterRequest $request2)
{
$input = Input::all();
$validation = Validator::make($input, $request->rules());
$validation2 = Validator::make($input, $request2->rules());
if ($validation->passes() and $validation2->passes())
{
  Users::create($input);
  Register::create($input2);
  return Redirect::route('users.main')
  ->withSuccess('Created');
 }

 return Redirect::route('users.create')
 ->withInput()
 ->withErrors();  
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `withErrors` would only return the latest errors.

Comment: My question is how do I show the multiple erros, since I have 2 different request and rules.

Comment: If I hit the button create it show the first validation erros if I pass the first validation the second error message show's and I want it to show at the same time

Comment: brother, you are totally on a wrong path

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it totally wrong. a request is a single request. though laravel supports request inside request in this scenario what i see is that you are trying to register a user into the system. do it like this.

create one request. say just `RegistrationRequest` and put all the form fields and the rules in it. use that request only to store the user like this.

```
public function store(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $validation = Validator::make($data, $request->rules());

    if ($validation->passes()) {
       $user = User::create([
          'username' => $request->username,
          'name' => $request->name
       ]);
       $register = Register::create([
         'blabla' => $request->name,
         'username' => $user->username
       ]);
       return Redirect::route('users.main')->withSuccess('Created');
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.create')->withInput()->withErrors();  
}
```

this is just a demonstration as per the actual problem you are facing is that you are trying a wrong approach, there are another ways to do this.and also validation errors are thrown and redirected to the create view like automatically. so you don't have to do it on your own

Comment: Yep I thought of this aproach and maybe it's the best one. I was going with 2 Request because I thought I could reuse when I want to insert at one table, so I would have the validation of table 1 on the request 1 and the validation of the table 2 at the 2 request.

Comment: I agree, with the Laravel Validator facade, you have some greatful validation like `required_if` to make your validations depending on more that one table :)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the messages of validators and send them back as:

```
$errors = $validation->errors()->merge($validation2->errors())

return Redirect::route('users.create')->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
```